# MSSQL php select from one encoding and insert to another

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, encoding, collation

This is a little tricky - I have a db with tables encoded as utf-8, I also got 1 view with hebrew_ci encoding.

I need to select stuff from the view and insert it to one table, with a php script, how can I do it without massing up the Hebrew characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you could use PHP Multi-Byte functions, especially **[mb_convert_encoding](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)**.

Note that **hebrew_ci** is a collation, not a charset. I guess that the hebrew charset you use is **ISO-8859-8**, according to [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=328641&seqNum=11), and the fact that **hebrew_ci** seems to be a MySQL collation rather than a MSSQL one (check [this](http://www.collation-charts.org/)).